# How can I monitor Android device's battery status through LAN or the web?

Tags: battery, battery-life

I would like to know if there is a way to monitor the battery status of different Android devices across a LAN network. Ideally it would be a web browser interface that shows the battery level of each device on the network that has this app installed.

Is there a native approach or, if not, an app for this?

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts, mack! Just in case you wonder: I rephased your question slightly to avoid it from being closed as "off-topic" (*Is there an app for X*, see our [help/on-topic] for details). Now, good hunting!

Comment: Are the devices rooted? Is there a web server in the network that could be used with scripting? Would it be possible to have [ADB](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adb/info) installed on it?

Comment: Close Voters: There are solutions not involving a specific app, so this could be on-topic as asking for a "native approach" (*or* an app if there is none).